# Is it possible to install a custom ringtone using iTunes 12.7 or later?

Tags: iphone, ringtones

Is it possible to install a custom ringtone on an iPhone running iOS  11 using iTunes 12.7 or later?
If so, how?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You can manually drag your ringtones into the device connected with iTunes.

[image]

[Apple has an updated article here.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207955)

Comment: For me, this only works when under the device options (*Summary*), the option *Manually manage music and videos* is enabled.

Answer (score 4):

I confirm the answer by Cykor: once installed the iTunes 12.7 version, and with a device connected, there is no more a "Ringtones" section under the selected device; but dragging a .m4r file over the device sends that file to the device. That file will be usable as a ringtone for any event or contact. If the file is not the correct format or size (too long, for example) an error window will appear.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: in itunes 12.7 with iPhone 6S attached by USB, dragging in an .m4r that worked before, onto anywhere in itunes (iphone view, main view, tones view, anywhere) does not work. I tried dragging single and multiple M4Rs, no go. Grr.

Comment: I have the same setup here, and it tested it on two different Macs with El Capitan and Sierra, both when the iPhone is connected via USB and WiFi.

Check the image, because you need to have that kind of visualization active (main view), and to drag the file on the device section relative to the iPhone. Dragging it anywhere else doesn't work.

Comment: I figured it out: it was because it was a different computer than the "home itunes" of the iphone. On the other computer it worked.